# How to Make One Method Run After the Other?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like my startButton to glow after it has faded in (see code below).  The title of my question isn't the most fitting, but I didn't know how else to phrase it.  Hopefully there's  quick solution.

To make my startButton transition into the screen:

```
-(void)transitionStartButton{
    transition = YES;
    CATransition *fromTop = [CATransition animation];
    fromTop.duration = 1.0;
    fromTop.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    fromTop.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
    fromTop.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    [_startButton.layer addAnimation:fromTop forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];
    transition = NO;
    [self glowStartButton];

}
```

TO make the button glow:

```
[self.startButton startGlowingWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] intensity:0.8];
```

I tried to simply place it one after the after, but it didn't work (the glow starts before startButton finishes fading in).  ***I would like the glow to start after it has stopped fading.***

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Rather than `CATransition`, use block-based animation (e.g. `UIView` class method `animateWithDuration`, and use rendition with `completion` block), so you can specify what animation to initiate upon the completion of the prior one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use setCompletionBlock:. This executes after the CAAnimation (so something like this):

```
CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    [self.startButton startGlowingWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] intensity:0.8];
}];
```

I think the animation is being done on another thread which is why it is executing at the same time.

More help:
http://samplecodebank.blogspot.com/2013/06/CATransaction-setCompletionBlock-example.html

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your help, I tried this and it works perfectly for the button, but in the background I have a UIView that moves across the screen (not using CAA Animation).  I think it is running on the same thread, how would I change it to another thread?  Thanks

Comment: It it using the UIView animteWithDuration method? Can you give me more details about the problem? Is it not supposed to be moving?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already written your "`startGlowingWithColor:`" method, it sounds like all you really need here is a repeating NSTimer, which you'd kick off at the end of your fade in. In that timer method, you could make certain "`transition == NO`" before doing the glowing animation.

I'd recommend NSTimer's method named:

[`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a)

making sure the "`repeats:`" parameter is set to YES and that you keep a property (or ivar) around for the timer so you can invalidate (cancel) it when you're ready to kill it.

*EDITED TO ADD:*

You say you've implemented this:

```
faded = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(startGlowingWithColor:) 
    userInfo:startGlowingWithColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] intensity:0.8] repeats:YES];
```

with this bit in your `glowStartButton` method:

```
[[self.startButton startGlowingWithColor:[(NSTimer *)faded] ];
```

What you really want to do is:

```
NSDictionary *userInfoDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor whiteColor], @"color", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8f], @"intensity", nil];
faded = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(startGlowingWithColor:) 
    userInfo:userInfoDict repeats:YES];
```

(you were setting up the userInfo dictionary incorrectly).

And in:

```
-(void)startGlowingWithColor:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSDictionary *userInfoDict = timer.userInfo;
    if(userInfoDict)
    {
         float intensity = [[userInfoDict objectForKey:@"intensity"] floatValue];
         UIColor *color = [userInfoDict objectForKey:@"color];
         ...
         ...
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for answering so quickly!  Is this what you mean?      [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:transition selector:NO userInfo:(nil) repeats:YES]; - sorry if I sound a bit silly, I'm fairly new to iOS development and am just curious about this.  :)  Thanks!

Comment: (That came up with an error - "Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC"

Comment: actually it would be "`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(startGlowingWithColor:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]`".  "`startGlowingWithColor:`" would have to be changed to take only one argument, e.g. "`startGlowingWithColor:(NSTimer *)timer`", and if you want to keep the intensity and color, you could pass that along via the userInfo dictionary.

Comment: Hello Michael, I tried this - 'faded = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(startGlowingWithColor:) userInfo:startGlowingWithColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] intensity:0.8] repeats:YES];' and then in my glowStartButton method I did this - '[[self.startButton startGlowingWithColor:[(NSTimer *)faded] ];' but it did not work, I feel like I'm missing out something really silly here!  Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for all your help, but I just wanted to let you know that I tried John's solution below and that's the one which I have implemented (but changed things up a bit).  Thanks!